# How to save an audio file in mp3 format.Why android does not have this basic support?

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

How to save an audio file in mp3 format.Why android does not have this basic support?

**To save as 3GP:**

```
 mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

 private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }
```

1. I tried to convert 3gp file to MP3 using [Lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/),but If want to use
   Lame,I need NDK.I am trying to convert without using NDK([reference](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI)).Is it any
   possible to way to do this?
2. Why MediaRecorder.OutputFormat class does not have basic mp3 support in Android?

Answer (score 2):

1. Not that I know of. You don't necessarily have to use the NDK to build Lame yourself, though, you could take a precompiled .so, include it, and just use JNI. Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/yhirano/Mp3VoiceRecorderSampleForAndroid), for example.
2. If I had to guess, I'd say it's because of patents. But who knows :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Trying to convert one encoded format to another without using NDK.
The process of converting one form or encoded data to another is called "transcoding". The way transcoding works (as far as i know) is - decode file format A >  RAW format > encode raw file to format B. All this is heavy signal processing work and lot of pointer access (..a lot). It is not efficient to do this in java and C/C++ is  the best .So you cannot avoid some native NDK calls and cannot avoid using C/C++

2) MP3 format is not a free format. There is company called technicolor (Check: http://mp3licensing.com/mp3/index.html) which controls the licencing for mp3 encoders. Be noted that if you are bringing out a product with mp3 encoders, you have to get licence for them (check the licence agrement) and it is not free. So android being an open source OS cannot give mp3 encoding. You can to use third party encoders. Read the licence agreement from the website i mentioned.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Regards,
Shrish

Answer (score 0):

(Update)

MP3 is officially supported by android, but only for DEcoding:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

> Core Media Formats:  MP3   •  Mono/Stereo 8-320Kbps constant (CBR) or
>   variable bit-rate (VBR)   MP3 (.mp3)

You can use mpeg4 as an alternative.

You can set it up with:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
```

Comment: This does not encode to mp3. If you look on your source link, there is a dot indicating that android has a decoder for mp3 and can play them. There is NOT a dot under the encoder column.

Comment: You're right. I missread when I posted. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set your outputformat of the recorder to `mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);` and the resulting recording will be an mp3 file. I have used this.

Comment: No, stock android CANNOT output mp3 format. It is a proprietary format and is not built in. What you got back when doing this was an mp4, which whatever player you were using happily played back just fine.

Comment: Sir, i have used this code in a recording application that i was developing at the time. The recording is saved as an ".mp3" in my SD card. Try it. Tested it in jellybean and Lollipop

Comment: The fact that you got a file with an mp3 extension DOES NOT mean it is an mp3 encoded file. What you got was a file with whatever encoding you chose with mRecorder.SetAudioEncoder. The resultant file was played back properly because the program you used to play it back was clever enough to recognise the correct encoding DESPITE the false extension

Comment: I don't know that. From the answers above android can't encode MP3's. Maybe i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your file created by MediaRecorder has .mp3 name suffix it will be not real mp3. Real MP3 file starts with ID3 tag, not with 0x00..ftyp3gp4'

Comment: This is not an answer to the question "how to save an audio file in mp3 format?"